# How to set APScheduler timezone and execute task through an hour range?

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

```
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone='US/Eastern')
scheduler.add_job(get_scores, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='8-18', minute='*/15')
scheduler.start()
```

I need this code to execute every 15 minutes from 9am - 5pm M-F EST. But for some reason it is doing:

```
Next wakeup is due at 2021-07-22 08:00:00-04:00 (in 47626.905794 seconds)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

timezone needs to be in the add_job, like:

```
scheduler.add_job(get_si_data, trigger='cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='8-18', minute='*/15', timezone='US/Eastern')
```

Comment: No, the scheduler timezone is used when missing from the trigger.